# Mysql Query Optimization for Temporary table

Tags: mysql, database

Could someone help me with Mysql Query optimization?

Query:

```
SELECT
lm.lead_id,lm.lead_title,lm.lead_active,lm.lead_da te,
la.lead_assign_add_date
FROM
lms_lead_master lm
LEFT JOIN lms_lead_assign la ON lm.lead_id = la.lead_id
WHERE
lm.lead_active = '1'
GROUP BY
lm.lead_id
ORDER BY
la.lead_assign_add_date desc
```

Explain shows

> lm table uses Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort in Extra.

```
Index : lm -> PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_status_id` (`lead_status_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_source_id` (`lead_source_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `opt_master` (`lead_active`,`lead_date`)
la ->PRIMARY KEY (`lead_assign_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_assignee` (`lead_assignee_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_assigned` (`lead_assigned_to_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_user` (`user_id`),
KEY `fk_lms_lead_id` (`lead_id`),
KEY `lead_assign_date` (`lead_assign_add_date`)
```

How to avoid Temp Table and File sorting?

Thanks in advance.
S. Chile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a close look at the document here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html you will find your answer

> If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if
>   the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the
>   first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.

And your query does the same

- ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause.
- ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the  first table in the join queue